# How do I define a connection string to connect to SQL Server from a Windows application?

Tags: sql-server, windows, c#-3.0

I'm an ASP.NET web developer. I have created a Windows application for retrieving data from SQL Server. Here's my app config and class file for retrieving data from SQL Server:

*App.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Data Source=INFY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NEWBULKSMS;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

*Code that attempts to connect to SQL Server*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Mysql
{
    public static string ConString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ConnString");
    public static string InsertResult = "0";
    private static Hashtable paramCache = Hashtable.Synchronized(new Hashtable());
    private static MySqlParameter[] DiscoverSpParameterSet(string spName, bool includeReturnValueParameter)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(Mysql.ConString))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(spName, cn))
            {
                cn.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                MySqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

                MySqlParameter[] discoveredParameters = new MySqlParameter[cmd.Parameters.Count]; ;

                cmd.Parameters.CopyTo(discoveredParameters, 0);

                return discoveredParameters;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is that the right way to connect to a SQL Server database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your connection string seems fine but your code is attempting to connect to SQL Server using MySql classes. This is wrong. Instead of `MySqlConnection` you should be using `SqlConnection`, instead of `MySqlCommand` - `SqlCommand` and so on.

All the classes that starts with `MySql` belong to the `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` namespace are are designed to work with MySql.
To work with Sql Server you need to use the classes that starts with `Sql` and belong to the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace.

I would start by removing the `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` line from the top of the code and then fix all the compilation errors by replacing MySql classes with Sql Server classes.

Comment: I follow your Solution and Solved all compilation error but i get this error runtime : 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'

Comment: That is a different problem - your connection string is not stored in the app.settings part of the config file but in the connectionstrings section.

Comment: ok. Thanks. I got solution by replacing connString with this line : public static **string ConString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ToString();**  and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string like bellow and you have to change from MySql to SQL and add using System.Data.SqlClient insted of using MySql.Data.MySqlClient that you already added in your project.................

```
public static string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
public static string InsertResult = "0";
private static Hashtable paramCache = Hashtable.Synchronized(new Hashtable());
private static SqlParameter[] DiscoverSpParameterSet(string spName, bool includeReturnValueParameter)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(spName, sqlConnection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command);
            SqlParameter[] discoveredParameters = new SqlParameter[cmcommandd.Parameters.Count];
            discoveredParameters=command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ccommandn.Close();
            return discoveredParameters;
        }
    }
}
```